# How does one compile a 64 bit macOS application with NASM application using CMake?

Tags: macos, assembly, cmake, nasm, mach-o

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeASM_NASMInformation.cmake) setting `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT` should be sufficient, however this does not seem to be the case.

I expected the following to create a valid build configuration for a macOS application using the macho64 file format.

```
project(hello_world ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT macho64)
add_executable(hello_world source/main.asm)
```

However, when running make with `VERBOSE=1`

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm   -f macho -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/source/main.asm.o /hello-world/source/main.asm
/hello-world/source/main.asm:6: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
/hello-world/source/main.asm:7: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
/hello-world/source/main.asm:8: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
/hello-world/source/main.asm:9: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
/hello-world/source/main.asm:12: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
/hello-world/source/main.asm:13: error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/source/main.asm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

We can clearly see the 32 bit version of mach-o is passed to the format flag instead of the expected 64 bit version: `macho64`.

**Versions**

- CMake 3.12.2
- NASM 2.13.03
- macOS 10.14

Comment: The compiler is checked at the `project()` call. Probably, you need to move setting the `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT` variable **before** that call.

Comment: That's what it was, doh!  If you create a answer I'll go ahead and accept that.  Thanks @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is checked at the `project()` call.

You need to move setting the `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT` variable **before** that call.